# What do you call modeling complex geometry using very minimal cages?

Tags: modeling, geometry

I've seen artist using incredibly complex geometry using strategically placed cages with subdivision surfaces applied.
What do you call the technique used to modeling complex geometry using very minimal cages?

Comment: What are very minimal cages, can you clarify with picture?

Comment: Modeling from zero? Manipulating a finished work further?  You may want to see the Lattice Modifier, Mesh Deform Modifier, Sculpting.

Comment: http://wiki.polycount.com/wiki/Subdivision_Surface_Modeling

Comment: a technique using subdivision mod to create complex shapes using a incredibly small amounts of cuts. the created cage seems so basic, it appears deformed without the sub mod.

Comment: Its a very minimalistic way of box modeling, prior to subdivision.